# How do I properly apply catch the error in my code? Swift Xcode Clean Architecture

Tags: swift, xcode, clean-architecture

I am currently implementing some code for a sign up screen (using swift clean architecture) - I have functions to be triggered when the signup button is pressed and when there is an error. I will paste the code below for assistance:

```html
import UIKit

protocol SignupFormErrorLogic {
    func showValidationError(_ message: String)
}

class SignupViewController: UIViewController, SignupFormErrorLogic {
    

    
    var interactor: SignupBusinessLogic?
    var router: (NSObjectProtocol & SignupRoutingLogic)?
 
    
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
    

    
    private func setup() {
        let viewController = self
        let interactor = SignupInteractor()
        let router = SignupRouter()
        
        viewController.interactor = interactor
        viewController.router = router
        interactor.router = router
        interactor.viewController = viewController
        router.viewController = viewController
    }
    
    
    @IBOutlet var fullNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    
    @IBAction func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func signupButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let request = Signup.Request(
            name: fullNameTextField.text!,
            email: emailTextField.text!,
            password: passwordTextField.text!
        )
        
        interactor?.createAccount(request: request)
    }
    
    func showValidationError(_ message: String) {
        let alertCtrl = UIAlertController(title: "Oops! An error occurred", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertCtrl.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.show(alertCtrl, sender: self)
    }
}
```

when I run the simulator, enter the details for the account I want to create, and click signup, it triggers my error request, but I don't know what the problem is. Should I be applying the do/try/catch block to figure out the issue? if so where/how should I apply it?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what do you mean under the 'error request'. Is `showValidationError(_ message: String)` method being called? If so, you should check your code in interactor, since you Signup button's action is calling interactor. Perhaps it has a bug in validation logic.

Comment: yes, showValidationError is being called - what is the appropriate way of getting it to print the error code?

Comment: well, the error happens in interactor, and if you want to print it in console, then you should write this code in interactor (or any other class that performs validation and can produce this error), and only pass a user friendly error message to the view for displaying in alert (since nobody wants to see error codes in alerts). In other words you should find the place where error occurs (using breakpoints can be helpful) and print this error in appropriate place. You can also use debugger’s `po` command to print it when the breakpoint triggered.